# Apache Cordova Ripple Error

Tags: cordova, plugins

Suddenly `ripple` began to put out the error in `Chrome`, after I was add `NFC plugin`.

below error message in console.

> Failed to initialize the NfcPlugin nfc is not supported on ripple.

Top page is open for no error, but error message appears when next page is opened.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: There is no support for NFC in ripple! You will have to test your app on a real device with NFC.

Comment: thank you for you replay. I made simple new project without NFC plugin. but same error appers. Top page is open for no error, but error message appears when nex tpage is opened via <a> tag.

Comment: Both Chrome uninstall and cordova cache clear was no effect.